# Android Calendar Instance url issue

Tags: android, android-calendar

Ok, I have searched and searched and cannot find a single person who has this same issue as me.

I use "content://com.android.calendar/instances/where" to get back instances based on the start date between values. I have a Nexus S with CM9 installed and this works great. My friend's Evo 4G with CM7 2.3.7 installed cannot. His says this is a bad url.

I had to resort to using events url and this is fine. However, his phone doesn't have the "availability" column. Also, events that might have changed start/end times seem to still come up in my query for just those starting in the next 15 minutes, for example, when they are starting the next day or later. I want to use instances but seems like I cannot.

Am I missing something here? I know they are undocumented apis but that doesn't stop anyone else from trying to use them as well. I just hope that there is some way to get the level of detail I need.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out by loading up CM7 on my second Nexus S that "instances" are indeed present. Possibly a RC or earlier then stable revision of CM7 had a bug in it. My friend loaded the latest and was able to get instances without issue.

Hopefully anyone else who might run into this issue will find this question helpful in their situation.